# Simulate a form post with nested resources arrays using curl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, http, rest, curl

How to use curl to make a http post on a form with nested attributes using application/x-www-form-urlencoded, instead of application/xml?

With XML it works just fine:

```
curl -i -X 'POST' -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' http://localhost:3000 -d '<user><name>John Doe</name><emails><email><address>jdoe@gmail.com</address></email><email><address>jdoe@yahoo.com</address></email></emails></user>'
```

And the result:

```
Parameters: {"action"=>"profile", "controller"=>"users", "user"=>{"name"=>"John Doe", "emails"=>{"email"=>[{"address"=>"jdoe@gmail.com"}, {"address"=>"jdoe@yahoo.com"}]}}}
```

But, I'm trying to accomplish the same result without xml.

I tried like this:

```
curl -i -X POST -d 'user[name]=John Doe&user[emails][email][address]=jdoe@gmail.com&user[emails][email][address]=jdoe@yahoo.com' http://localhost:3000/
```

But it didn't worked:

```
Parameters: {"user"=>{"name"=>"John Doe", "emails"=>{"email"=>{"address"=>"jdoe@yahoo.com"}}}}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

would you please try the following:

```
curl -i -X POST -d 'user[name]=John Doe&user[emails][][email][address]=jdoe@gmail.com&user[emails][][email][address]=jdoe@yahoo.com' http://localhost:3000/
```

Note the `[]` behind `[emails]`

Comment: Almost: `Parameters: {"user"=>{"name"=>"John Doe", "emails"=>[{"email"=>{"address"=>"jdoe@yahoo.com"}}]}}` The array part works, but only the last email is being considered.

Comment: Hmm, this works. : `curl -i -X POST -d 'user[name]=John Doe&user[emails][]=jdoe@gmail.com&user[emails][]=jdoe@yahoo.com' http://localhost:3000/`

Comment: Thanks, Michael. In your last comment you've forgotten the address attribute. But with your help I was able to figure out: `curl -i -X POST -d 'user[name]=John Doe&user[emails][email][][address]=jdoe@gmail.com&user[emails][email][][address]=jdoe@yahoo.com' http://localhost:3000/`. The `[]` is after `[email]`