# How can i add values for a field from another model in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `user model` and `language model` where the language model contains list of languages and the user model contains the information of the user. In user model there is a `field` called `language` where the user should select a language from the language model. And for all these i do not have form and i want to pass the `id` of the language when creating new user and it should save the language for the user. I use `curl` to create and update.

So please tell me how i can do this? Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think nested attribute is what you need. You can learn more about it here : 
[Active Record Nested Attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

Additionally for simulating nested attribute calls using curl, you can look at this post :

[Simulate a form post with nested resources arrays using curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996290/simulate-a-form-post-with-nested-resources-arrays-using-curl)